# Using callback for ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to prevent a function to execute before get a value from ajax, I'm trying using async:false it works but deprecated. So, I'm using callback like what I found on internet. It's works too, but the browser still tell me if the callback is not the function. Here's my code

```html
function User() {
    this.nama;
    this.nis;
    this.pass;
    this.role;
    this.url = "http://localhost/elearning-web/";
    
    this.Login = function(call) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",url:this.url+"dologin.php",data:"nis="+this.nis+"&pass="+this.pass,
            success:function(e){
                call(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I check the console.log it's show what I want to display, but the browser tell me if the call (callback) is not a function. Thanks in advance

Comment: where did you even define the function "call"

Comment: Show how you call `User.Login`as per [mcve]

Comment: What are you passing to the function as "call" ?

Comment: Sorry about that, but I'm not define the call function, so it's must be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is already achievable using Promise API, and yes, jQuery supports it too.

You just need to change the `Login` function as below:

```
function User() {
  // .. other code truncated for brevity

  this.Login = function() {
    return $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'your_url'
      // Note that `success` function has been removed from here
    });
  }
}
```

Now this solves a lot of problems. First of all, the caller of `User.Login` doesn't need to pass a callback function. The login function can just be used like this:

```
var user = new User();

user.Login()
  .then(function(e) {
    // `e` is accessible here
  });
```

Second, there can be unlimited number of `.then()` chained with each other, providing better code readability.

Third, you need not to validate the callback to be a function since `.then` accepts a function as its argument (validates it for free).

Fourth, `success` callbacks are deprecated by jQuery. `.then()` uses the new syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The `call` argument, that you are passing to the method `Login` must be a function, for example:

```
var call = somethingFunction(){ return 'called!';}
var user = new User();
user.Login(call)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declarate a call function the pass it to User.Login(call);

```js
function call1(e) {
  console.log('Hi, from call ', e);
}

function User1() {

    this.Login = function(call) {
        // simulating $.ajax http request ;]
        setTimeout(function() {
          call(';)');
        }, 2000);
    }
}

var user1 = new User1();
user1.Login(call);

// in your case
function call(e) {
  console.log('Hi, from call ', e);
}

function User() {
    this.nama;
    this.nis;
    this.pass;
    this.role;
    this.url = "http://localhost/elearning-web/";
    
    this.Login = function(call) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:this.url+"dologin.php",
            data:"nis="+this.nis+"&pass="+this.pass,
            success:function(e){
                call(e);
            }
        });
    }
}

var user = new User();
user.Login(call);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```